# Oracle - Lock que previna SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, select, pl-sql, oracle11g

Lock que previna SELECT

A situação é seguinte :

Uma aplicação ERP (Totvs) com diversas tabelas
Todas estas tabelas usam como chave primária 
um campo padrão
R_E_C_N_O_

A aplicação (creio) cria um novo registro
com um 
select max(R_E_C_N_O_)+1

Preciso porém que uma package plsql
crie registros em algumas destas tabelas
mas ao concorrer com o ERP ocorrem erros
de ORA-00001: restric?o exclusiva

Minha pergunta é :
**Existe alguma síntaxe em que seja possível
"lockar" o max(R_E_C_N_O_) no caso
de uma tabela específica ?**

A ideia é ter um "wait" e não permitir
que a aplicação ERP e a package tenham
o mesmo R_E_C_N_O_ futuro.

Lembro que não tenho como mudar o ERP
Tudo deveria ficar na package PLSQL

E claro minimizando a possibilidade 
de DEADLOCKs

Comment: Porque não cria uma `sequence`?

Comment: Grato @Everson , mas como disse a aplicação já existe não posso mudá-la tenho de fazer um bloco plsql conviver com o que já existe e evitar o conflito de PKs

Comment: Você tem acesso de DBA nessa base Oracle? Se não me engano, nas bases TOTVS em Oracle, os R_E_C_N_O_s são implementados utilizando triggers e sequências. No caso, seria apenas o caso de você utilizar esse mesmo objeto SEQUENCE que o TOTVS.

Comment: Tenho o acesso , no nosso caso ao menos não é por TRIGGER e pela camada de aplicação, creio que internamente seja mesmo max(recno)+1